# File upload through ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

Following is my ajax function

> 

```
$(document).on('click','.formsubmitbtn',function(){
  var owner = $("#formowner").val();
  var remark = $("#formremark").val();
  var unreline_id = $("#formurelineid").val();
  var cat = $("#formcat").val();
  var action = $(this).attr('action');
  var doc = $("#doc").val();
  $.ajax({
    "url":"{{url('formsubmit')}}",
    "type":"POST",
    "data":{
      "owner":owner,
      "remark":remark,
      "unreline_id":unreline_id,
      "cat":cat,
      "action":action,
      "doc":doc
    },
    success:function(result){
      console.log(result);
    }
  });
});
```

where doc is a file.

How do send the file values to the controller.

Plz help.

Comment: You are sending the values to the controller, which would be accessible in the `Input` facade or `Request` object in the controller

Comment: I tried to print the array for $_FILES['doc'].. It gave me the following error.

Comment: MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 218:

Comment: I get other values..

Answer (score 1):

Do like this.

```
<form id="upload">
   <input type="file" name="file">
   <button type="submit">Upload</button>
   </form>

<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#upload").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var form=($(this)[0]);
        var formdata=new FormData(form);
        $.ajax({
                    url:'url.php',//url to route for a controller
                    type:'POST',
                    data:formdata,
                    enctype:'multipart/form-data',
                    processData:false,
                    contentType:false,
                    success:function(data){
                    //if upload will succesful
                    },

                    error: function (data) {
                    //if upload fails
                    }
        });
    });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks James... I got the solution

Comment: Not mention it.